# "after", "before" with or without past perfect

Tags: meaning, tense, usage, conjunctions

1) I had seen her before she saw me. 2) I saw her before she had seen me. Sentence 1 is clear to me but I have a doubt about sentence 2. Can we use "before" with past perfect tense? Likewise can we use "after" in place of "before" in the above sentences?

Comment: **before** and **after** with past perfect is a bit awkward why not place it all in the past simple? "**I saw her before she saw me"**

Comment: When the birds left the tree,
the cat had caught one of
them. Is this sentence correct?

Comment: I would suggest placing **already** after **had**.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence:  "*I had seen her before she saw me" is a bit awkward.  I'd use "I had seen her by the time she saw me" or "I saw her before she saw me."

The second sentence:  "*I saw her before she had seen me" should be "I saw her before she saw me" or "I had seen her by the time she saw me."